# Elastic Search Monthly Rolling index with custom routing

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I am trying to figure out the how to create a monthly rolling index with custom routing (multi-tenancy scenario) , with these requirements :

*WRITE flow* : Each document will have a timestamp and the document should be indexed to the appropriate backing index based on that timestamp and not to the latest index. Also, write requests will have a custom routing key (eg: **customerId**) so they hit a specific shard.

*READ flow* : Requests must be routed to all backing indexes. Requests will have a custom routing key specified (eg: **customerId**) and results must be aggregated and returned.

*Index creation* : Rolling the index should be automated. Each index should have a custom routing key (eg: **customerId** )
Wondering, what are the options available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very feature, called [time-series data stream](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tsds.html), will be coming in the upcoming ES 8.5 release.

The [big difference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tsds.html#time-bound-indices) between normal data streams and time-series data stream is that all backing indexes of TSDS are [sorted by timestamp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tsds.html#tsds-index-sorting) and all documents will be written in the right backing index for the given time frame of the document, even if that backing index is not the current write index, which means if your data source lags (even by a few hours), the data will still land in the right index. Also all documents related to the same dimension (i.e. `customerId` in your case) will end up on the same shard.

Another difference is that the [ID of the documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tsds.html#tsid) is computed as a function of the timestamp and the dimension(s) contained in the document, which means there can only be one single occurence for a given timestamp/dimension pair (i.e. no duplicate).

Technically, you can already achieve pretty much the same with normal data streams, however, the underlying optimizations related to storing docs in the same shard and the ability to write documents to older backing indexes won't be possible since you can only index documents in [the current write index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html#data-stream-write-index).